# error: incompatible license. Entering rescue mode

Tags: boot, 20.04, boot-repair

This is Ubuntu 20.04 in a VMware VM. Everything was fine the last time I used it, and I did a clean shutdown as far as I can remember, but now I get this message on boot:

[image]

This isn't a dual-boot machine, there is just this Ubuntu. I found a few discussion of the "Incompatible license", but they're from 2013-2015, so very old and there are comments that those solutions no longer work. What does this error even mean, and can you help me fix this Ubuntu installation?